# Run code on specific core/thread?

Tags: c, embedded, powerpc

I am writing some bare metal embedded software on a multi core system. I am initializing core 0 thread 0 as the master core and trying to now execute code on the others cores/threads. My question is how would I execute code on a specific core/thread without an OS such as Linux to set the affinity? Is there a generic way to know how to do this or is it processor specific? The processor is a NXP T2080 with 4 cores each with 2 threads.

Comment: Yes, it is processor specific

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Okay I figured. Any experience doing something similar. I just don’t know where to start. The best approach I can think of is moving the threads instruction pointer to the code I want it to execute but I’m not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately haven’t done that myself, only worked that low level on single core systems. But would assume that’s the way to do it. The processor should have a data sheet to explain what’s needed

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Alright thanks for the advice!

Comment: Are you doing this with *no* underlying hardware abstraction layer or OS?

Comment: Each core will have its own PC, start address, SP and so on. It is not really different from having x different single-core CPU:s, except they can access the same memory. I don't know the specific part though.

Comment: @JeremyKerr No abstraction. I’m setting registers and controlling the hardware with a combination of C and some assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not using any OS here, it's entirely up to your code to manage all execution, including that on other threads. The way you manage that will mostly be up to your own code, but there are a few hardware interactions involved:

1. On system init, you'll need to pick a primary thread. It sounds like you've already done this, but you don't state how.

   On ppc machines, each thread has a unique value for its Processor Identification Register (PIR). If you *know* the values of the PIRs, then you can just check the PIR to see which is the primary. If you don't know the PIR values, then you can use an atmoic set-and-test to pick your primary: the first thread to increment a value becomes primary, others are secondaries.
2. Depending how you implemented (1), the other threads will need to be doing something else. Are they idle? or spinning in a loop?

   If they're idle, you'll then need to bring them out of idle (after which they'll enter the reset vector). Once they're executing the code in the reset vector, you'll need to ensure that they don't do the same thing as the primary, so have some way to send them off to their own secondary-specific code.

   If they're spinning in a loop, it'll be up to the primary to get them out of that loop (say, by setting a flag that they read) and executing useful code.

   Since you've mentioned you're using C, those secondaries will probably need their own stack. You'll need to initialise their per-thread C runtime appropriately, using their own stack pointer in `r1`.
3. The definition of that "useful code" is up to you, and the way that you get those pocessors running that code is your own design.

   A simple method would be to have a central list of tasks, where the primary enqueues tasks, and each secondary dequeues a task from that list (with appropriate locking, of course) and executes it.

   Since you want to control affinity, your solution will be a little more complicated (say, per-thread queues), but it needn't be substantially different.

Take a look at how we do this in skiboot (a firmware for 64-bit POWER machines),  if you'd like an example: https://github.com/open-power/skiboot/blob/master/asm/head.S#L305.

Comment: Thanks for all the useful info. I will start looking into the source code for how to implement this!